# How do you obtain a formatted date and time for the current locale in C?

Tags: c, datetime, formatting, locale, ctime

What C function should I call to obtain a formatted date and time for the locale where the program is being executed?

I'm asking this question because I have run into a problem using the ClamAV daemon API. The `VERSION` command returns the date and time of the latest virus definitions, but the code uses a call to `ctime` to format it. As far as I can tell `ctime` does not format the datetime according to the current locale and uses the English abbreviations for days of the week and the month in the returned string. This causes problems as my Java program which uses the ClamAV API *does* respect the current locale and thus expects the day of the week and month name to have the local abbreviations.

The datetime format would need to be in the same format as that produced by [ctime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/ctime/):

> Www Mmm dd hh:mm:ss yyyy
>
> Where Www is the weekday, Mmm the month in letters, dd the day of the month, hh:mm:ss the time, and yyyy the year.

I could rewrite the Java program to always assume English dates but I'd be happier to submit a patch to ClamAV as it seems like a bug on their side to me.

Comment: yes ctime doesn't create a localized date/time string, it calls asctime which creates a US formated string,but why do you assume this is a bug? I would think that if there is some utility to parse the date/time string to compare dates it would be easier to keep one format (even though a numeric version would be better).

Comment: But this means that all users of the ClamAV API who are using non-US locales have to specifically parse the date using the US locale. This is easy enough to do in Java but might be difficult in other languages? It would be annoying to do manually, especially if you didn't speak English and you had to look up all the names and abbreviations.

Comment: That being said, I'll probably modify our code and also submit a bug report/patch, and see what the ClamAV devs say.

Comment: It would seem to be best if the ClamAV API provided the date/time in a locale-independent format - like a good old UNIX epoch timestamp.

Comment: @caf definitely, but I think they have been thinking about people calling it via telnet and wanting it to be human-readable.

Comment: Since the current VERSION command doesn't take any arguments, you could add an optional "tsformat=UNIX" argument or similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strftime("%c", ...` should give you the preferred date and time representation for the current locale.  Or (still with `strftime`) you can emulate `ctime`'s format but with `%b` for current-locale month abbreviation, `%a` for current-locale weekday abbreviation, and so on.